# how do I import an excel data into an existing mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project, where the users can create a new contact group as well as be able to update existing ones with excel data.

creating a new contact group is not the problem, but inserting the content of the document into the database has been a major problem for me.

or which format can be imported easily into the database with php.

The data looks like this:

|name | |email                   | |telephone|

|me        | |we@us.com| |080234444| 
etc

any advice, suggestion or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: That is a bit vage. What exact data do you want to insert in the DB?

Comment: "*which format can be imported easily into the database with php*"?  [CSV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html).

Comment: pointing you towards a youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfahu3ggy8c&list=PLEBB401EA1B5A2EBC&feature=view_all

Comment: @juergend I have updated my question with data format

Comment: @eggyal any hint (idea) on how to go about CSV import?

Answer (score 0):

MySql can easily import CSV* data from a file using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. If you need to parse other excel data, you will need extra methods and logic to read the file and manually populate the database.

You can read more info on [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

*Essentially any delimited text (TSV etc)

Please note there are many limitations/gothchas with delimited data, for example, the inability to hold unescaped commas in csv text. Be sure you source file adheres and respects CSV rules or else you may end up with corrupt data.

EDIT

Now that you have provided some example of your data you may want to try this (or something similar):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE `your filename` INTO `Table` 
Fields Terminated BY '|' 
Lines Terminated BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4, @Col5)
SET Name = TRIM(@Col1), Email = TRIM(@Col3), Telephone = TRIM(@Col5)
```

Here, you load the data into temporary variables, which then get instered into the table.
Note the file must exist on the local machine.

EDIT

Try this fixed SQL

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your filename' INTO TABLE `Table` 
Fields Terminated BY '|' 
Lines Terminated BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4, @Col5)
SET Name = TRIM(@Col1), Email = TRIM(@Col3), Telephone = TRIM(@Col5)
```

Comment: please where should the file in question be. getting file not found (Errcode: 2)

Comment: You need to provide a LOCAL path to a file on the MySQL server machine